# How to output the first-stage result of iv2sls in statsmodels by python?

Tags: python, statsmodels

When I use the iv2sls in statsmodels and output the result by summary() or summary2(), it can only show me the final result. How can I get the first-stage result by statsmodels just like it is in stata?

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.sandbox.regression.gmm import IV2SLS
forfuntable=pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel('2sls_just4fun.xlsx',header=0))
a=IV2SLS(forfuntable["log(a)"],forfuntable["log(b)"],forfuntable["c"]).fit()
a.summary2()
```

Comment: Could you show some code if you have some?

Comment: @Xilpex I have already put the code in the question. The code is easy, and it is really seems like copy directly from its documentation. Here's the link of documentation: [link](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.sandbox.regression.gmm.IV2SLS.html)

Comment: Ok... Thanks!!!